# Outputting One long string as author in Natbib?

Tags: natbib

I'm using Natbib to display my references in text.
For example,

```
@misc{DrinkingWater,
      author = "Water Quality and Health Council",
      title = "Drinking Water Chlorination A Review of Disinfection Practices and Issues ",
      month = "September",
      year = "2015",
      url = "http://www.waterandhealth.org/drinkingwater/wp.html",

}
```

If I invoke this using `\citep{source}`, I only get

> (of Concerned Scientists, 2015)

Moreover, I've referenced wikipedia many 3 times , and for that it shows

> (Wikipedia, 2015b)

How can I get rid of the letter?

For example I have the sources:

```
@misc{LoveCanal,
      author = "Wikipedia",
      title = "Love Canal : Aftermath ",
      month = "September",
      year = "2015",
      url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love_Canal#Aftermath",

}

@misc{SilentSpring,
      author = "Wikipedia",
      title = "Silent Spring ",
      month = "September",
      year = "2015",
      url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_Spring",

}
```

and when I source them I get (Wikipedia,2015) and (Wikipedia, 2015a)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: @egreg Thanks, that fixed my author problem! But how about the 2015a, 2015b etc...?

Comment: You want to distinguish the citations, don't you? But without an example it's not really easy to say more.

Comment: @egreg Is this good enough or do you want to see my packages and such?